# how display add_action output in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function

hi there is a code in below

```
function sumobi_edd_show_download_sales() {
$sales = edd_get_download_sales_stats( get_the_ID() );
$sales = $sales > 1 ? $sales . ' sales' : $sales . ' sale';
echo '<p>';
echo  $sales;
echo '<br/>';
echo sumobi_edd_get_download_count( get_the_ID() ) . ' downloads';
echo '</p>';}add_action( 'edd_product_details_widget_before_purchase_button', 'sumobi_edd_show_download_sales' );
```

i need to diplay output of this code to another file

Comment: do_action('edd_product_details_widget_before_purchase_button');

Comment: Do you mean to save the result of your code into a file?

Comment: yes i want to display result in other file

Comment: Call the function directly? There's not enough information in your question to provide a clearer answer.

Comment: i want display sales number for each product from EDD plugin